# C++ - can execute function in diffrent way?

Tags: c++

In this code:

```
void Window::oops()  { printf("Window oops\n"); } 
void TextWindow::oops() { 
printf("TextWindow oops %d\n", cursorLocation);
}
TextWindow x; 
Window      a; 
Window     *b; 
TextWindow *c; 
a = x; a.oops();   // executes Window version 
b = &x; b->oops(); // executes TextWindow or Window version 
c = &x; c->oops(); // executes TextWindow version
```

What does it mean that `b = &x; b->oops();` will execute the TextWindow **or** Window version? How is it decided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `oops()` is virtual, the `b->oops()` call will use the `TextWindow` version. If it is not, it will use the `Window` version.

Comment: -1 for  `If it is not, it will use the Window version`, since it WILL call the `TextWindow` version.

Comment: @Nawaz: no it won't. If the function is not virtual, it will use the Window version, because b is of type Window*.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not specifically stated, I'm assuming that `TextWindow` is derived (directly or indirectly) from `Window`.

In this case, the basic question is whether `oops()` is a virtual member function or not.

If `oops()` is virtual, then a call via a pointer or reference is based on the *dynamic* type -- the type of the object actually referred to by the pointer/reference.

If `oops()` is not virtual, then a call via a pointer or reference is based on the *static* type -- the type of object the pointer is defined to point at, *regardless* of the type of the object it's actually pointing at.

```
struct Window { 
    void oops() { std::cout << "Window::oops()\n"; }
    virtual void oops2() { std::cout << "Window::oops2()\n"; }
};

struct TextWindow : Window { 
    void oops() { std::cout << "TextWindow::oops()\n"; }
    virtual void oops2() { std::cout << "TextWindow::oops2()\n"; }
};

int main() { 
    Window w;
    w.oops();      // Both of these print "Window::...".
    w.oops2();

    TextWindow tw;
    tw.oops();     // Both of these print "TextWindow::...".
    tw.oops2(); 

    Window &w2 = tw;
    w2.oops();     // oops() is not virtual, and we're using a reference to a Window, 
                   // so this invokes Window::oops().

    w2.oops2();    // oops2() is virtual, so even though w2 is a reference to a
                   // Window, this invokes TextWindow::oops2(), because the reference
                   // refers to the object tw, which is a TextWindow.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = x; a.oops();   // executes Window version
```

This one causes object slicing. See this wiki entry : [Object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

```
b = &x; b->oops(); // executes TextWindow or Window version
```

Using this, you call the virtual function polymorphically. It will call the TexTWindow versiom, not Window version!

```
c = &x; c->oops(); // executes TextWindow version
```

It just calls the virtual function, using the pointer of same type, as the dynamic type of the object, which in this case if `TextWindow`.

Comment: `b->oops()` will call the TextWindow version *only* if `oops()` is virtual, and we can't tell if it is from the code snippet in the question.

Comment: I don't see `oops` declared as `virtual`. There is no way to determine if the classes are `polymorphic` from the code snippet OP posted.

Answer (score 0):

It's basic [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) :

b being a pointer to Window, it can point to a Window object or an object of a type inherited from Window. The inherited type can then re-implment the oops() function (if oops() is specified virtual in the Window definition).

To allow this, the c++ compiler will add additional informations to route the function call in the object data, almost always in the form of a [v-table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

That allows you to manipulate a set of Windows, call the base member function and don't worry about what the object will really do in the end. That object will can then implement functions in a specific way for it's specific child type.

See the simple examples in the wikipedia page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming